# Spring-mobile site preference in viewresolver not in each controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mobile

The [spring mobile documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/html/device.html#spring-mobile-site-preference) shows how to implement a separate mobile view layer like below :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(SitePreference sitePreference, Model model) {
        if (sitePreference == SitePreference.MOBILE) {
            // prepare mobile view for rendering
            return "home-mobile";
        } else {
            // prepare normal view for rendering
            return "home";
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would prefer to apply the different view name(prefixing it with a folder), in the view resolver. How would I do this ?

(edit : No answers, normally spring config issues have a few responses ... have I asked a particularly stupid question ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems valid to me. The most straight-forward answer that I can think of is having the views splitted and make use of the site preference value in the folder name:

```
/views/normal/home.jsp
/views/mobile/home.jsp
```

(The view resolver's prefix should be "/views/", of course).

Now in the controller you can have:

```
return sitePreference.name().toLowerCase() + "/home";
```

You cannot use two separate resolvers, as the controller cannot decide which viewresolver to use, but only which view.

As for the resolver selection, that can only be controlled via the "order" property which is completely out of scope for this use case.

---

Edit: I sensed the code smell in having the same logic duplicated in all the controller methods.

So, in order to keep that logic in one place, try to make use of a custom `HandlerInterceptor` which would add the prefix to the view name in the `postHandle` method. You only need to grab the current SitePreference instance yourself, based on the request , which should be perfectly possible.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is a good suggestion. However is there a way to do all this is in only the view resolver itself ? And not check site preference in the controller at all ?  I am using latest version, and trying to be annotated as possible.

Comment: However, you can of course subclass the view resolver and add this functionality: maybe as a pluggable strategy, not tightly coupled to the SitePreference thing.

Comment: OK, is their an example of an interceptor altering the prefix of the viewResolver ? How would I do this ?

Comment: In the `postHandle` method of the interceptor you are able to access the `ModelAndView` instance that is about to be used. There, you can extract the view (if the view `isReference()`) and change it to `yourPrefix + originalView`.